# Boro cab service in New York City

Tags: new-york-city, taxis

New York City recently added a [separate hail cab service](http://www.nyc.gov/html/tlc/html/passenger/shl_passenger.shtml) for the outer boros and Manhattan north of 110th street.

The information I can't find is how does this work for the New York airports?

Previously the cabs at the airports yellow cabs used to pick up passengers at an airport and carry people to any boro in New York City. Now that two different cab services are in play should I be waiting for the Boro Cab in order to go to a boro other then Manhattan?

Comment: The first sentence of the third paragraph is difficult to parse, you might want to edit it.

Comment: All Please don't change the spelling of the 'boro' to 'borough'.  It's spelled that way on purpose!

Comment: @Karlson: Why?  I'm all for a more fonetik speling of Inglish, but nobody will find this question if you intentionally misspell key words.

Comment: @jpatokal Because in New York they are called Boros rather then proper Inglish

Comment: The taxis are apparently indeed called "boro taxis" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boro_taxi), but the boroughs themselves are still boroughs.

Comment: @Karlson not so. Boro is the name of a company. Borough is a place, even in NYC. Do a search for "bronx boro tax" for instance, what do you see? All of the hits state borough.

Comment: If I didn't drive by the sign [like this](http://librapix.com.s3.amazonaws.com/street-and-traffic-signs.com/332.jpg) every day I would agree with you.  So yes administrative division is a "borough" even though New Yorkers refer them as "boros" an in no other way.  So please leave them be.

Comment: @Karlson I disagree (sign not withstanding), but its ur ?

Comment: @Karlson That's nonsense, New Yorkers call their borough “borough”. “Boro” is just an unusual spelling/shorter form of the same word.

Comment: @Relaxed You must know better.  But I still would like to have it left the way it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Boro Taxis **may not** pick up passengers via curbside hail/taxi stand from La Guardia or Kennedy airport. They **may** take you *to* the airport, and, as with a standard Yellow taxi, may not refuse to do so. They are also allowed to perform *prearranged* pickups from the airports, if you contact a dispatch company. In this sense, they are no different from any of the hundreds of Black Cars at the airport at any given moment (with which they often share dispatchers/a fleet/management).